# Three balls inside a cone

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

Given a cone with slant height $4$ and radius $2$. Inside there are three identical balls touching each other and lateral surface of the cone. Two of the balls touch the base. What is maximal radius of the balls?

Comment: Could you provide an illustration?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't draw it.